# How do neural networks process images and data that isn't just numbers?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

From what I understand, neural networks use mathematical operations and calculations to process data. We need numerical values to calculate error so the model can correct itself, we need to calculate the gradient of the error function, etc. We need numerical values to process data, and images are not numerical data, so how does the neural network analyze and it and perform operations on it. The labels of the files are also strings so how does the model calculate an error? Futhermore, how is this implemented in python

I tried using AI and ChatGPT to answer my question, but unfortunately, I didn't get an answer.

Comment: if `I didn't get an answer` means the answer you received is too complicated for you to really understand it, try telling your agent to reword the answer considering your background and age (i.e. "answer like I am 18 y/o with basic technical knowledge").

Comment: `images are not numerical data` that is completely wrong. Image data is very much numeric data. Every pixel is numeric data. Image processing software works on those values. Photoshop and other image processing software perform matrix operation on those pixels, often using signal processing algorithms

Comment: Everything your computer holds can be represented by just numbers, be it an image, some text or some music. An image is made up of lots of pixels, each of which can be represented by three numbers giving the "amount" of red, green and blue to show (often this is a number between 0-255, e.g., (0, 0, 0) is black and (255, 255, 255) is white).

Comment: `I tried using AI and ChatGPT` and `I didn't get an answer` are strongly correlated. ChatGPT doesn't understand what you ask, it produces text based on the statistics of the question and its training set. If you want to understand how image processing works, much less NNs, you have to read. Even a digital photography book will explain filters, convolution, etc

Answer (score 2):

We can convert all information to numbers. This is how computers work. For example. you can convert pixels into 3 number - Red, Green, Blue (RGB). Like if Red, Green and Blue were all equal to the maximum value which is most often 255, the output color would be white.